# Using Mailchimp V3 API to fetch all user activities

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm trying to fetch all member activities using the "new" (V3) Mailchimp API.

```
http://string:<key>@<region>.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/<list_id>/members/<member>/activity?count=100&offset=0
```

But I can't seem to receive more than 50 records.

Does anyone know if it's even possible to fetch all the activities of a member or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The schema for that resource](https://api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/Lists/Members/Activity/Collection.json) specifies a max of 50.